# How to organize/receive emails on one account while sending from another

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, gmail, accounts

I have had a Yahoo account for a number of years and recently got a Gmail account. Since my Yahoo account has all my emails since forever saved into folders that are helpful for me to keep organized, I have set up my Gmail to forward all emails Gmail receives to my Yahoo account, so that I can continue to use the Yahoo system while giving people my new Gmail address.

So, in my Mail app I use Yahoo. But I would like the emails that I send to appear as being sent from my Gmail address.

I have tried adding the Gmail account and then setting Gmail as the default account. That didn't work. I have also tried clicking on Yahoo in the settings and then going to the outgoing server setting and entering in smtp.gmail.com. That didn't work either. I also tried deleting my Yahoo account and re-adding it, in case the order that the accounts were added had anything to do with it.

Any advice on how I can continue to use Yahoo to organize my emails, but have them send AUTOMATICALLY from my Gmail address?

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want all email send from one account (i.e. gmail) you can set that up in Mail preferences.

Open Mail Preferences then select Composing:

[image: composing]

Now select your gmail in the "send new messages from:"

Obviously in Mail you will need Yahoo and Gmail accounts.

Alternatively you can use the "Reply to" in Mail app.

For that Start a new mail and go View - "Reply to Address Field" or simply use shortcut alt+cmd+R. Then enter your reply to address. Now when you send new emails or you reply to emails it will use the selected email.

[image: reply to]

The third option: if you are really serious with that, you can use the Terminal app located in your Utility folder.

Type "`defaults write com.apple.mail UserHeaders '{"Reply-To" = "reply-to@address"; }'"` (excluding the outermost quotation marks) and replace reply-to@address with the address you want to be used for replies.

Read more [here](http://email.about.com/od/macosxmailtips/qt/etalwaysreplyto.htm)

Comment: The problem is that this does not affect replies, only new messages.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz I must have missed that in the question.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for can't be done on Mail.app, it will work on Gmail web interface, and it may work on Yahoo web interface. Other than that, good answer.